# How to validation a url inside a quill editor link

Tags: html, typescript, angular8, ngx-quill

I am using a quill editor with my angular8 project. On the same there is an option to add url with the help of 'link'. Could I know, is there any way to validate the url which I will enter for the 'link' textbox as shown images below. Following are my codes

**quill editor module**

```
 editorConfig= {
    formula: true,
    toolbar: [      
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['link']
    ]
  };
```

**html**

```
<quill-editor [modules]="editorConfig" [style]="{height: '200px'}"></quill-editor>
```

[image]

[image]

How to validate links inside the textbox which is marked on the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I find a way to resolve this question

First we need two function to override the default link handler and the function of snowtooltip save

```
import Emitter from 'quill/core/emitter';
import { message } from 'antd';

/**
 * override Snow tooltip save
 */
export function SnowTooltipSave() {
  const { value } = this.textbox;
  const linkValidityRegex = /^(http|https)/;
  switch (this.root.getAttribute('data-mode')) {
    case 'link': {
      if (!linkValidityRegex.test(value)) {
        message.error('链接格式错误，请输入链接 http(s)://...');
        return;
      }
      const { scrollTop } = this.quill.root;
      if (this.linkRange) {
        this.quill.formatText(this.linkRange, 'link', value, Emitter.sources.USER);
        delete this.linkRange;
      } else {
        this.restoreFocus();
        this.quill.format('link', value, Emitter.sources.USER);
      }
      this.quill.root.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      break;
    }
    default:
  }
  this.textbox.value = '';
  this.hide();
}

export function SnowThemeLinkHandler(value) {
  if (value) {
    const range = this.quill.getSelection();
    if (range == null || range.length === 0) return;
    let preview = this.quill.getText(range);
    if (/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(preview) && preview.indexOf('mailto:') !== 0) {
      preview = `mailto:${preview}`;
    }
    const { tooltip } = this.quill.theme;
    tooltip.save = DtysSnowTooltipSave;
    tooltip.edit('link', preview);
  } else {
    this.quill.format('link', false);
  }
}
```

then use these function in editor

```
const SnowTheme = Quill.import('themes/snow');
SnowTheme.DEFAULTS.modules.toolbar.handlers.link = SnowThemeLinkHandler;
```